# React Navigation Bottom Tabs Navigator plus Modal Screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have the following code to create a Tab using React Native Navigation v6.x:

```
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function MyTabs() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

The HomeScreen has a button which should call a Modal Screen.

My question is: How would I add this modal screen in my Navigator to call it from HomeScreen and how would be this call code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to include the modal in the navigator to open it from the homepage.

You could do something like this:

```js
const HomeScreen = () => {
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);

  function _myModal() {

    return(
      <Modal
        animationType="slide"
        visible={modalVisible}
        onRequestClose={() => {setModalVisible(false)}}
      >
        <Text>Hello, I am a modal!</Text>
      </Modal>
    )
  }

  // your code
  return (
    <View>
      {/*your code*/}
      <Pressable
        onPress={() => setModalVisible(true)}
      >
        <Text>Show Modal</Text>
      </Pressable>
      {_myModal()}
    </View>
  );
};
```

[The React-Native documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/modal) has an example for class component as well in case you're working with these, and more info that should help you as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open modal screen from your home page then you should create a home screen stack navigator and add two screen in that stack(home and modal screens), and then navigate to that modal by pressing button.

**Tab Navigator**(RootNavigation MyTabs)

```
...
function MyTabs() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeStack} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

**Stack Navigator**(HomeStack)

```
cosnt Stack = createStackNavigator();

function HomeStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="HomeScreen" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="ModalScreen" component={ModalScreen}
         options={{ presentation: 'modal' }} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

**HomeScreen**

```
export default function HomeScreen({navigation}) {
   return (
      <View>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('ModalScreen'}>
              <Text>Open ModalScreen</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
   )
}
```